# Accept() and SIGUSR1 are being tripped accidentally

Tags: c, sockets, ipc

Hi I'm building a program that uses a signal handler shown below ...

```
struct sigaction pipeIn;
pipeIn.sa_handler = updateServer;
sigemptyset(&pipeIn.sa_mask);
pipeIn.sa_flags = SA_ONESHOT;

if(sigaction(SIGUSR1, &pipeIn, NULL) == -1){

    printf("We have a problem, sigaction is not working.\n");
    perror("\n");
    exit(1);    

}
```

The problem is that this handler is getting tripped when it's not supposed to. The only thing that should send the SIGUSR1 signal is my child process which exists inside an infinite while loop which listens for incoming connections. The child process is forked as you can see below. I redo the pipeIn handler to run a different function that the child process uses which the parent does not. The code is shown below.

```
while(1){

    newSock = accept(listenSock,(struct sockaddr *)&their_addr,&addr_size);
    printf("A\n");
    if(!fork()){
    // We want to redefine the interrupt
        pid_t th;
        th = getpid();
        printf("child pid: %d\n",th);
        pipeIn.sa_handler = setFlag;
        if(sigaction(SIGUSR1, &pipeIn, NULL) == -1){

            printf("We have a problem, sigaction is not working.\n");
            perror("\n");
            exit(1);    

        }

        close(listenSock);
        kill(getppid(),SIGUSR1);
        waitForP(); 
        }*/
        close(newSock);         
        exit(0);
    }
    close(newSock);
    //waitForP();
    //break;
}
```

When I run this code, I will make a call from another computer to connect to my server program that you see here. It will `accept()` the one request from that computer just fine, but then the child process will eventually get around to sending SIGUSR1 to the parent process. However the parent process receives the SIGUSR1 signal before the child process even gets to send the signal. The handler trips the function before it should ... then the child process finally gets to kill the signal and the handler goes off the 2nd time. Lastly the `accept()` function goes off again even if there are no new connections being produced and the incoming ip address is from a weird ipv6 address that is random. I don't know what's going on. Any help would be great.

Comment: Do you perchance get EINTR and an error from the accept call? It looks like you're not checking the return value

Comment: Ya I did implement a version of this code where I check out the return value of the newSock. For whatever reason the second it is triggered, accept() returns -1. So I've filtered that with my fork() statement. The first time that accept is triggered, it seems to get the right socket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeat after me: always check for error returned from a [system call](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) (which [`accept(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/accept.2.html) is - you are getting `-1` instead of a socket descriptor, `EINTR` in [`errno`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/errno.3.html) and undefined connecting address).

Comment: Yes I do have a version of the code that checks for such errors which works for me, but I was wondering why it would even try to return a socket fd in the first place when no one else is trying to connect.

Comment: Hmm, so you don't wait indefinitely. Signals are "software interrupts" - they allow you to break out of blocking system calls.

Answer (score 1):

This might seem obvious, but have you compiled your code with full warnings on and assured you don't have any? Mysterious behavior is often caused by errors that are only mentioned by the C compiler if you ask it...